# Annotate with count for each user then order by date of latest occurrence

Tags: python, django

I want to get the count of unread messages for each `user_from` which ordered by the date of last message from her/him.

```py
class Chat(models.Model):
    user_from = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    user_to = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    is_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    added_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I'm seeking for some queryset(s) outputing like this:

Output queryset:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Count, Max
query_set = Chat.objects.values('user_from').annotate(unread_count=Count('user_from')).filter(is_read=False).annotate(last_time=Max('added_on')).order_by('-last_time')
```